# Using i18n with RequireJS in Visual Studio 2015 Cordova App project

Tags: windows, cordova, visual-studio-2015, internationalization, requirejs

I got a weird thing happening when I try to run the Windows application produced by the Cordova project in Visual Studio 2015.

The application uses the third-party libs i18n along with RequireJS to translate any text based on the language chosen by the user. **The problem is that no text is loaded without any form of error or whatsoever.** The same exact code works for Android and iOS builds just fine.

I went into debug to find out something weird, whatever language I submit will return the value undefined. Even weirder, if I require specifically the root file manually, it will load the english version of the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a sample project that mimics the exact problem.
[CordovaTest.rar](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-QgmNqbAsWKNENLMXF0WE1yZms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're running into with Windows is its support of [qualifiers in file names to support localization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965372(v=win.10).aspx).

> Resource qualifiers are folder and filename modifiers that identify
>   the context in which a particular version of a resource should be
>   used.

Contexts can include locales which is what you've run into here. Long story short, here's what it looks like is happening:

1. Your app's default language is set to "fr" right now
2. When the app starts on Windows, it sees that you're running as the "fr" local and it hides any folders qualified as targeting other locales. In this case, your app has an "en" folder that is seen as a qualifier for the English language, and Windows will hide the "en" folder contents.

It's really hard to explain the first time around, so let me know if you want clarification on the above and I can try to re-phrase it.

To fix your issue, you would want to use folder names that are not seen by Windows as qualifiers. For example, you could name your "en" folder and call it "English". Then, change your RequireJS bundle configuration to define the "english" locale:

`define({
    "root": {
        "Test" : "TestFR"
    },
    "english":true
});`

Now when you run your app, you'll see it working.

Comment: You, sir, are my hero of the week. I have been on that specific issue for some days already just scratching the surface of the problem. I'd vote you up but I don't have the rep for it. 
THANKS!

Comment: Great! I'm glad this helped. I've been bitten by this issue before, and looked for a way to turn of qualifiers all together, but no luck.